# Wordpress Magic fields dropdownlist limit of values

Tags: wordpress

Hy guys,

i created a dropdownlist by getting values from magic fields:

```
<?php $dvs = new WP_Query(); ?>
<?php $dvs->query('cat=3'); ?>

    <div class="dvs-menu">

        <!-- List -->

        <p>VS</p>

        <select id="dvs-list">
            <?php while($dvs->have_posts()) : $dvs->the_post(); ?>
                <option class="dvs-list" title="dvs-<?php echo get('dvs_year'); ?>" value="<?php echo get('dvs_year'); ?>">
                    <?php echo get('dvs_year'); ?>
                </option>
                <?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>
        </select>

    </div>
```

I have about 20 values in there, but whatever i do, only 10 will be shown. Is that a problem of WP, MF or the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hitting the standard pagination limit (10 posts per page.) Pagination is on by default (makes sense for most Loops) but obviously it's not a good option for your dropdown list.

Try adding the `nopaging` option to disable pagination:

```
<?php $dvs->query('cat=3&nopaging=1'); ?>
```

See [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more details.